Using arrayformula function does not copy automatically to new rows in Google Sheets
I have a sheet like this:
A       B           C       D
entry   profit/loss value   balance
300     profit      12      312

I'm going to do this:

I add the balance manually
The value (from the second entry, in fact from C3) should be D3-D2
The profit/loss is if value>0,"profit","loss".

I did the following formulas (tried all of them to see which one works), but it does not copy automatically to new cells:
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(C:C>0,"Profit","Loss"))
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(C>0,"Profit","Loss"))
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(C2:C>0,"Profit","Loss"))

And also did this for value column.
How can I do this?
I just note that I have another excel file in OneDrive and it copies automatically, but I'm not sure why Google Sheets doesn't do this or what should I do.

the first and third formulas should work fine. Could you share a sample sheet where you demonstrate the issue?

@z.. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GOHucYVcPgNBk1IVTLWuQIQnFaIa_n23HSTwK0V3BRA/edit?usp=drivesdk see if you can see that

where did you enter the arrayformula?

You haven't provided a range to your array formulas I changed the formulas in B3 and C3 to:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C3:C="",,IF(C3:C>0,"profit","loss")))

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D3:D="",,D3:D-D2:D))


Thanks, but I want it to include the whole column, not from 3:5 only. Can you help me? Suppose I'm going to have rows up to 1000 or even more. Currently it's tided to what you provided.

see the updated formula.
